# C segmentation error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lergab(char *gab);
void criamatriz (char **alunoresp, int *resp);

int main(){
    char gab[20];
    char alunoresp [100][21];
    int resp[80];

    //lergab(&gab);

    criamatriz (&alunoresp[100][21], &resp[80]);

    printf ("\n\n%d\n", alunoresp[0][0]);

    printf ("%c\n", alunoresp[0][1]);
    printf ("%c\n", alunoresp[0][1]);
    printf ("%c\n", alunoresp[0][19]);






    return 0;
}

void lergab (char *gab){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
        scanf("%c\n" , &gab[i]);
    printf("%c", gab[19]);
}

void criamatriz (char **alunoresp,int *resp){
    int i = 0, j;

    //for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++){

        scanf ("%c", &alunoresp[i][0]);

        for (j = 0; j < 80; j++){
            scanf ("%d", &resp[j]);
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 80; j=j+4){

                int g = 1;

                if ((resp[j] + resp[j+1] + resp[j+2] + resp[j+3]) != 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'e';
                else if (resp[j] == 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'a';
                else if (resp[j+1] == 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'b';
                else if (resp[j+2] == 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'c';
                else if (resp[j+3] == 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'd';

                g++;

        }
    //}
}
```

This code is supposed to read a number as ASCII code, then read 80 numbers and convert them to their respective character, like a electronic test scanner. 
I.E:
0
0
1
0
is c,
1
0
0
0
is a,
1
0
1
0
is an invalid option (for you should only sign one answer per question).

Code is just a test, my objective here is create a matrix that contains 100 candidates with 20 answer in each of them, along with their identification code, which is the first number read as ASCII, thus alunoresp[100][21] is declared.
I'm getting segmentation error every time i try to run it on gcc, any ideas?

Edit:

Thanks for the help on the indices thing. I didn't notice.
Stil, even after fixing that i keep getting segmentation faults.

Code now looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lergab(char *gab);
void criamatriz (char **alunoresp, int *resp);

int main(){
    char gab[20];
    char alunoresp [100][21];
    int resp[80];

    //lergab(&gab);

    criamatriz (&alunoresp, &resp);

    printf ("\n\n%d\n", alunoresp[0][0]);

    printf ("%c\n", alunoresp[0][1]);
    printf ("%c\n", alunoresp[0][1]);
    printf ("%c\n", alunoresp[0][19]);






    return 0;
}

void lergab (char *gab){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
        scanf("%c\n" , &gab[i]);
    printf("%c", gab[19]);
}

void criamatriz (char **alunoresp,int *resp){
    int i = 0, j;

    //for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++){

        scanf ("%c", &alunoresp[i][0]);

        for (j = 0; j < 80; j++){
            scanf ("%d", &resp[j]);
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 80; j=j+4){

                int g = 1;

                if ((resp[j] + resp[j+1] + resp[j+2] + resp[j+3]) != 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'e';
                else if (resp[j] == 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'a';
                else if (resp[j+1] == 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'b';
                else if (resp[j+2] == 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'c';
                else if (resp[j+3] == 1)
                    alunoresp[i][g] = 'd';

                g++;

        }
    //}
}
```

Comment: Please raise the warning level of your compiler, all of these are straight forward errors that should be diagnosed. Also please read a good tutorial or book on the difference between pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your program:

- **You are calling `criamatriz` function incorrectly** - rather than passing a pointer to the end of the arrays, you should be passing arrays themselves, and
- **Your `criamatriz` function takes a 2D array incorrectly** - you are passing it like a pointer to a pointer, which is incorrect. You should be passing it like a pointer to an array of 21 elements.

Here is how you should declare and define your `criamatriz` function:

```
void criamatriz(char (*alunoresp)[21], int *resp);
```

Call it like this:

```
criamatriz(alunoresp, resp);
```

Comment: Are you sure? My goal is to create an array of 21 element arrays, shouldn't I declare it like **alunoresp?

Comment: @LucasSartori A pointer to pointer is a way for creating jugged arrays (i.e. arrays where each row may have a different size). Regular 2D arrays are arrays of arrays. You can pass them like pointers, or like arrays of arrays with fixed size of the last dimension (i.e. `char alunoresp[][21]`).

Comment: @LucasSartori By the way, your fix is still incorrect: you do not need to take pointers there, simply pass the two arrays by providing their names.

Comment: Okie Dokie! It actually worked, thanks so much man. And by the way, should i just pass them like criamatriz(alunoresp, resp) ?

Comment: @LucasSartori Yes, that is how you should pass them.

Answer (score 2):

```
criamatriz (&alunoresp[100][21], &resp[80]);
                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

You're exceeding the maximum allowed indeces in your array there. e.g.

```
int x[10]; // allows index 0->9
```

Comment: Even after fixing that I keep getting segmentation fault :(

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, Lucas!

> I'm getting segmentation error every time i try to run it on gcc, any ideas?

Step 0 is to get yourself a debugger, this won't be the last time you encounter a similar issue.  If you're using `gcc`, it's a good bet that `gdb` is available on this system.  Try running your executable with `gdb` and X marks the spot!

```
gdb ./my_binary
```

... then ..

```
run
```

execution will halt right where the invalid memory access occurred.  You can examine the state of the program (local variables, etc) using the `print` command and you can walk up and down the stack with `up` and `down` respectively.

For example:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./go 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004004fd in inner () at ./go.c:6
6       int ohno = *bad;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004004fd in inner () at ./go.c:6
#1  0x0000000000400512 in outer () at ./go.c:11
#2  0x000000000040052d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf88) at ./go.c:16
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000004004fd in inner () at ./go.c:6
#1  0x0000000000400512 in outer () at ./go.c:11
#2  0x000000000040052d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf88) at ./go.c:16
```

Comment: *shrug*, I guess I could go to meta and find out the same thing.  But IMO OP needs this answer more than the others.

Comment: Comments are too terse.  I'll take the downvotes, it's worth it if Lucas can take advantage.

Comment: It would be a very different case if this question would serve *ANY* utility to someone other than who asked it.  Bottom line, it's a good candidate to be put on hold.  But in the meantime, I'll treat OP as if he were a colleague asking the same question.

Comment: *scoff*, the question or my answer‽

Answer (score 0):

When sending an array to a function, all you need to do is send the base address of that array,

In your code

```
criamatriz (&alunoresp[100][21], &resp[80]);
```

this line is actually sending the address of the `alunoresp[100][21]` element, which doesnt even exist.

An array defined as `int alunoresp[100][21]` has maximum indices `[99][20]` since indices start from `0`

You need to call the function like this,

```
criamatriz (alunoresp, resp);
```

Since the name of the array contains the base address (address poitning to the first element) of that array.